# How to understand "with" in the sentence "It's a very busy time with us at the moment"?

Tags: prepositions

"It's a very busy time ***with*** us at the moment."

How to understand the prepostion "with" here?

Why use "with" not "for" here.
If they have similar meaning, what are their nuances?

Comment: It's a slightly unusual usage (usually the preposition *would* be ***for***). But if you must have an explanation for the "meaning", think of it as ***with us = [around] at the place we are***. Perhaps spoken to someone who's (metaphorically) *far* from where we are (they don't even know about how busy it is there). Or perhaps to add a nuance that *we* (as opposed to people working at *other* places) are busier than most.

Answer (score 2):

FumbleFingers has suggested some nuances which may have been **intended**, but there's no particular nuance which must be understood here.

There are many acceptable ways to phrase most common situations. Prepositions in particular are very fuzzy around the edges.